# Check one column's data type, if not number then return indications in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
   id floor
0   1     5
1   2     4
2   3     3
3   4     2
4   5     1
5   6    B1
6   7    B2
7   8    B3
```

I want to check if `floor` column's contents are all numbers, for the cells which are not numbers, then returns an indication by adding a new column `invalid floor`.

```
df['floor'].map(type).unique()
Out[259]: array([<class 'str'>], dtype=object)

df['floor'].dtype
Out[260]: dtype('O')
```

The expected result will like this:

```
   id floor          check
0   1     5            NaN
1   2     4            NaN
2   3     3            NaN
3   4     2            NaN
4   5     1            NaN
5   6    B1  invalid floor
6   7    B2  invalid floor
7   8    B3  invalid floor
```

How could I do that using `np.where` or other method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html):

```
df['check'] = np.where(df['floor'].str.isdigit(), None, 'invalid floor')
```

Or [`Series.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) with `\d+` for numbers:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df['floor'].str.match('\d+'), None, 'invalid floor')
```

---

```
print (df)
   id floor          check
0   1     5           None
1   2     4           None
2   3     3           None
3   4     2           None
4   5     1           None
5   6    B1  invalid floor
6   7    B2  invalid floor
7   8    B3  invalid floor
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible `df['check'] = np.where(condition, 'invalid floor', None)`, code like that?

Comment: @ahbon - yes, if add `~` like `df['check'] = np.where(~df['floor'].str.isdigit(), 'invalid floor', None)`